# And 16 million would serve during the second World War. Why 'would serve' not 'served'?

Tags: modal-verbs

Sometimes it is very difficult for non-native speakers to understand the meaning of 'would'. So, why do these sentences use 'would'? If I change 'would serve' to 'served', is this wrong? What is the difference betweeen 'served' and 'would serve'? If I change 'would reach' to 'reached' or 'would become' to 'became', do these sentences then have different meanings?

- In all, more than 4,000,000 Americans **served** in the armed forces 
  during the first World War. And 16 million **would serve** during the
  second one. 
  (the first one is 'served', why is the second one 'would serve'?)
- And, historians say, the sauce was probably first created in a Chinese community in northern Vietnam. Later, this sauce **would reach** Indonesia and be called kecap. 
  (why not 'reached'?)
- William Henry Harrison **would become** the ninth U.S. president. 
  (why not 'became'?)

Why do these example sentences need the word 'would'?

Comment: It is a shift of the temporal point of view from the present to a time in the past.   *He won the primary and **would go on** to become president.*   We are shifted there to the time of winning the primary. The presidency was still in the future at that point. The shift is not **needed**, merely allowed. There's a subtle temporal drama involved in this changing of perspective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Cambridge Dictionary

**[would](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would)** modal verb (FUTURE)

> used to refer to future time from the point of view of the past

---

> In all, more than 4,000,000 Americans served in the armed forces
>   during the first World War. And 16 million would serve during the
>   second one.

4,000,000 Americans served (WWI) - after that, in the future of this point in time - 
16 million would serve (WWII)

The same applies to your second phrase.

In the third, there is no mention to a previous date. I'm not sure about this one. Maybe it lack some omitted part centered in Harrison's previous life.